# iOS: How to increase a UITableView's "crop" beyond the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a touch event which removes a UITableView cell with an animation and then reinserts it further down the table. I'm using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` to add a different appearance to the cells that have been tapped, and they are kept together at the bottom of the table.

If the table contains a number of cells that fit on the screen without having to scroll, the functionality works as expected.

However, if I have more cells than would fit on the screen, I'm noticing what comes across as a graphical glitch when I call `reloadData()` (which is needed for the cells to maintain their correct appearance). The 'glitch' occurs when the tapped cell gets removed, and the following cells slide up, *but only* if the cell that slides in and stops at the bottom of the screen is the last one with the 'non-tapped' appearance. When that cell slides in, it initially has the 'tapped' appearance, but upon the reload, it then renders to show the 'non-tapped' appearance, which is the way I want it to look when it slides into the view.

Given that this works fine when the cells involved can all be seen at once, am I right in thinking that by extending the 'crop' of the UITableView, I might get around this problem?

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
tableView.contentSize.height += 150
tableView.bounds.size.height += 150       
tableView.frame.size.height += 150
```

Is there anything else I can try, or do I need to rethink the way I'm trying to achieve this?

Comment: please show the code of how you delete/insert your cells

Comment: Do not use reloadData, instead remove/insert rows incrementally. This should animate rows properly.

Comment: Post more code to explain how you use `dequeueReusableCell` to change appearance. Usually you would change data source and then either reload row or obtain cell directly via `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and manipulate it's appearance.

Comment: Sorry you're right, it's in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that I'm altering the appearance, and without `reloadData()` the true appearance usually gets lost... so seems to be required in my case. Fingers crossed it looks like I may have fixed it - had this issue for a while!, seems like the solution was based around re-arranging the order of actions before the reload took place... thank you for your help, though :)